# Noob question incoming - Cylinder Bevel

Tags: bevel

Brand new to blender and have what i think is a very basic question...

I have a basic cylinder and i done the loop cut and slide to create more horizontal vertices on there so i have some squarish faces to work with, but after doing that, i can only create a small bevel. I guess the bevel feature is only acting on the adjacent faces to the edge, which are now small. How is it possible to create a larger bevel?

In the end what i want to create is a cylinder with enough vertices so i can scult ( i tried this with an "untouched" cylinder, and the brush result was very distorted). Maybe im not doing this the correct way? Should i be using a remesh rather than manual cuts?

Thanks!

Bevel modifier
[image]

Bevel tool
[image]

Comment: You are right, the bevel only goes as far as the next edge or will give weird results with overlapping geometry. To avoid it, hit C while using the _Bevel Tool_ (for _Clamp Overlap_). The easiest way to get a larger bevel when you create a basic cylinder would be to first bevel the edge as far as desired and add the loop cuts afterwards. I'm no expert at Sculpting, only thing I can say is yes, more geometry is helpful, although with a simple mesh you could activate _Dyntopo_ which adjusts the mesh resolution dynamically while sculpting. But experienced sculptors prefer not to use it, I think.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann this is a good answer. PS: I sculpted a humanoid once, and I turned dynotopo on and off. Just another tool.

Comment: Well, as I said I usually don't sculpt. I've just seen tutorials of people who prefer a fixed mesh resolution with a multires modifier for better control.